# regEx for Instagram not working as intended

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a javascript that should detect hashtags and mentions and replace them. I am using this library: https://github.com/AnSavvides/jquery.linky

```
function _linkifyHashtags(text, links) {
    // If there is no search URL for a hashtag, there isn't much we can do
    if (links.hashtagSearchUrl === null) return text;
    return text.replace(/(^|\s|\(|>)#((\w|[\u00A1-\uFFFF])+)/g, "$1<a href='" + links.baseUrl + links.hashtagSearchUrl + "$2' target='_blank'>#$2</a> ");
}
```

The problem with this code is that the regEx only work when hashtags is written with spaces before (Like: "#hi #hello #lo")

If the hashtags is written with no space before, like this "#hi#hello#lo", the script is not detecting the hashtags.

I have tried to add possible none white character before also:

```
/(^|\s|\S|\(|>)#((\w|[\u00A1-\uFFFF])+)/
```

It works "half way". Suddenly every second hashtag with no space before becomes detected by the script.

I am no RegEx expert and have tried to read up on this, but I can't se how to get this part right. Anyone who knows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just remove the limitation on what can precede a tag as nothing is also a valid alternative now.

```
/#((\w|[\u00A1-\uFFFF])+)/g
```

You should also remove it from the replace accordingly, simplifying it to:

```
return text.replace(/#((\w|[\u00A1-\uFFFF])+)/g, "<a href='" + links.baseUrl + links.hashtagSearchUrl + "$1' target='_blank'>#$1</a> ");
```

Comment: I guess this is even a simpler solution.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
/(^|\s?|\(|>)#((\w|[\u00A1-\uFFFF])+)/
```

The ? after \s catches 0 or 1 whitespaces.

Comment: @LzyPanda, so matching nothing with the first group is also an option now. Why do you need it at all?

Comment: Hmm, ok. Is there a better solution to the problem?

Comment: @ndn yeah you're right i was just lazy and didn't  think it through. Yours is the better one.

Answer (score 0):

hey try this regular expression.

```
/(\s|\w)*[\#][\w]*/g
```

[Regex fiddle](http://refiddle.co/2epa)